# Android Youtube Api change VideoID

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

i working android Youtube Api.i successfully created project.i can play video and also can Skip video in button click.now i added second button and in this button's click i want to change video ID in onInitializationSuccess method
this is a my code

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "***********";
private String VIDEO = "*****", VIDEO1 = "*****";
private Button b1, b2;;
private YouTubePlayer player1;

private PlayerStyle style;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    youTubeView.setEnabled(false);
    style = PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS;
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int[] array = new int[] { 36000, 140000, 250000 };

            Random random = new Random();
            final int index = array[random.nextInt(array.length)];

            Log.e("randommmmmmmmmmmm", String.valueOf(index));

            player1.seekToMillis(index);

        }
    });
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int[] array = new int[] { 36000, 140000, 250000 };

            Random random = new Random();
            final int index = array[random.nextInt(array.length)];

            Log.e("randommmmmmmmmmmm", String.valueOf(index));
            // player1.loadVideo(VIDEO, index);
            player1.seekToMillis(index);


        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
        YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Oh no! " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    this.player1 = player;
    player1.setPlayerStyle(style);

    player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
    if(b2.isFocused())
        player.loadVideo(VIDEO1);

}
```

}

i try to solve my problem with

```
player.loadVideo(VIDEO,index);
```

but in this situation videoID changed but video  loaded every time when i click button
how i can  change Video ID in button click ,without load each time video?

Comment: dude,did u got the solution for this?\